# snowplow browser tracker request getting blocked in the browser

Tags: reactjs, snowplow

```
import { newTracker } from '@snowplow/browser-tracker'

newTracker('sp1', {{ my_url }}, {
  appId: 'app',
  plugins: [],
})
```

And I'm using it like

```
import { trackPageView } from '@snowplow/browser-tracker'
.
.
.
useEffect(() => {
  trackPageView()
}, [])
```

In the network tab, I can see the request to `{{url}}/com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow/tp2` getting blocked with status `blocked:other`.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off all the ad-blockers extenstions.